# How to iterate a dictionary inside a list which is again inside a dictionary to change a value of a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Appreciate your help.

I am looking for some help in understanding how to ask Python to go for the next line instead of using the same line from the code below. The line which I mean is the block starting from index 2 and then the next block from index 1.

```
'lines': {
        'line': [{
                'index': 2,
                'label': None,
                'display': None,
                'dirn': {
                    'pattern': 'XXXXXX',
                    'routePartitionName': {
                        '_value_1': 'internal-numbers',
                        'uuid': '{YYYYYYYYY}'
                    },
                    'uuid': '{XXXXXXXXX}'
                },
                {
                'index': 1,
                'label': None,
                'display': None,
                'dirn': {
                    'pattern': 'XXXXXX',
                    'routePartitionName': {
                        '_value_1': 'Internal-Agents',
                        'uuid': '{YYYYYYYY}'
                    },
                        'uuid': '{XXXXXXXX}'
                    },
]}
```

The above is an output that I receive for a GET request to CUCM.

I am trying the below query to update two or three lines at the same time using a loop but I am missing something out of it.

```
for i in phones:
    i = i.upper()
    j = ucm.get_phone(name=i)
    line_ct = j.lines['line']
    for line in range(len(line_ct)):
        rec_profile = j.lines['line'][line]['recordingProfileName']['_value_1']
        dn_pattern = j.lines['line'][line]['dirn']['pattern']
        dn_routePartition = j.lines['line'][line]['dirn']['routePartitionName']['_value_1']
        index_value = j.lines['line'][line]['index']
        line_data = {'line': 
                      [{'index': index_value,
                     'dirn': {'pattern': dn_pattern,'routePartitionName': dn_routePartition},
                    'recordingProfileName': 'TestingLab'}]}
        if rec_profile == 'XXXXX':
            ucm.update_phone(name = i, lines = line_data)
```

I am able to update if it is a single line. However not with two lines. TIA.